# Wishlist ajax request with Deferred Object

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred, deferred

I am using a function with an **AJAX** request to count items in my wishlist ( I am using a YITH wishlist plugin) everything is working fine but it's to slow. Each time I click on an item to add it to wishlist I need to wait 2/3 sec to update the counter so I was thinking that maybe I can do a small "hack" to update the counter before the ajax call and then if there's a success just leave it as it is.

Here's my code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ){
$(document).on( 'added_to_wishlist removed_from_wishlist', function(){
    var counter = $('#primary-menu .menu-crown');
    var mobile_counter = $('#mobile-menu .menu-crown');

    $.ajax({
        url: yith_wcwl_l10n.ajax_url,
        data: {
            action: 'yith_wcwl_update_wishlist_count'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function( data ) {

        },
        success: function( data ){
            console.log(data.count);
            counter.attr('data-count', data.count);
            counter.find('span').html(data.count);

            mobile_counter.attr('data-count', data.count);
            mobile_counter.find('span').html('('+data.count+')');
            if( counter.attr('data-count') == 5 || mobile_counter.attr('data-count') == 5 ){
                $.magnificPopup.open({
                    items: {
                        src: '#wishlist-info-popup', // can be a HTML string, jQuery object, or CSS selector
                        type: 'inline'
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});});
```

I was thinking to do that in beforeSend but I have no idea how to proceed with the counter and then "move it" to success.

Can you please advise where to start with that?

thanks!

Comment: You can increase the counter just on click. Then, if you get success response, do nothing, else, decrease the counter and display an error. Just like Stackoverflow does. (Try to upvote your question)

Comment: 2 3 secs are not very large scale for a response. You can set the loader on click for better user experience. After a response from plugin counter will be updated.